# WebApi in MVC3, cannot hit my API Controller (500 internal error)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api, routes

I have the below route mapped in my AreaRegistration:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        if (context != null)
        {
            context.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "API_Default",
                routeTemplate: "Areas/Test/AIO/api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new
                {
                    id = RouteParameter.Optional
                });
```

When I look at the Global.asax file, I can see the HttpRoute is being Registered, and is listed in the RouteTable.Routes as a {System.Web.Http.WebHost.Routing.HttpWebRoute}.

Problem is, when I go to the url... `https://myRoot/Areas/Test/AIO/api/AioApi/test` or `https://myRoot/Areas/Test/AIO/api/AioApi`, it's giving me a 500 internal server error.

I'm not sure how to view the actual error, when stepping thru the code I cannot see anything after it leaves Application_BeginRequest.

My controller code:

```
public class AioApiController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/<controller>
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
```

Any insight as to why I cannot hit the API controller? I can hit my regular MVC controller in the same context.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is WebAPI available with MVC3?

Comment: Your controller code has only 1 method: Get()?

Comment: Yes you can install WebAPI with MVC3. My api controller has all the standard methods (Get,Post, etc)... I only pasted in the one that I should be hitting.

Comment: Why are you going over https? Are you sure your program is listening on port 23 and has the certificate and everything set up correctly? For debugging, it's usually easier to just go over http

Comment: I'm at a corporate business, where we use https. Https is working for everything else, including my regular MVC controller. Everything is setup correctly... I use it all the time.

Comment: Update: I created a new MVC3 project locally at home, and I had the same 500 internal error. I had to add the NuGet .dlls to the GAC and that fixed it. Unfortunately, that didn't fix my problem at work, which the code is a bit more complex. :(

Answer (score 0):

One thing I found out with WebApi is that there are two Route collections: `System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection` and `System.Web.Http.HttpRouteCollection`. I believe (but can't remember) that you need to use the latter in order for your `ApiController` derivations to work properly (luckily the syntax is the same).